# I am trying to create an autocomplete search bar that queries for dynamically generated comments that exist within in child components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have a search bar within a parent component which can search for 'comments' that exist within child components. I would like the search bar to then show only the components with those matching comments.

I am considering using the context API or redux to accomplish this however, I am not sure if this is necessary or the right direction. I am new to React, so any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're getting the data there are a few options. Context API or redux (or any other state manager) would work as suggested, but if you're trying to avoid that you could either:

1) Instead of autocompleting the search box, just send the search term to the child in its props and filter the comments list inside the child as the search term changes.

2) Retrieve the comments for the child component in the parent, then if you want to update the child, use componentWillReceiveProps to check for updates from the parent.

3) pass a bound method to the child from the parent to send all the comments to the parent for search purposes

for all of these you would need to either send the search term to the child to filter the list or the filtered items to display.